# When using Session Variable to store username. WSGI application 'CMS.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module

Tags: django, django-views, session-variables, wsgi, django-wsgi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzxQb.png)

Above is my django project structure and i have two django apps.

I am using mongodb as my database and not using user authentication module.

I am using session variable to store username when user is logged. but i am getting error while using session variable.

raise ImproperlyConfigured(

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'CMS.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

`wsgi.py  ---> main project file`

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'CMS.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

`authentication/views.py`

```
def login(request):
    error_message = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username_value = request.POST.get('username')
        password_value = request.POST.get('password')

        try:
            user = SignUp.objects.get(username=username_value)
            # Check if the provided password matches the hashed password in the database
            if check_password(password_value, user.password):
                # Successful login
                response = HttpResponse("Login successful!")
                request.session['username'] = user.username

                return redirect('home')
            else:
                error_message = "Invalid username or password"
        except DoesNotExist:
            error_message = "User does not exist"

    return render(request, 'authentication/login.html', {'error_message': error_message})
```

`settings.py`

```
from pathlib import Path
from mongoengine import connect

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure--#u^llr^ji5f70u-vm-99-59(m4010v_$a%bga2-puf2-d%l*3'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mongoengine',
    'Student_management_app',
    'core',
    'authentication',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'CMS.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'CMS.wsgi.application'

connect('CMS', host='localhost', port=27017)
MONGODB_DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongoengine.mongoengine',
        'NAME': 'CMS',
        'HOST': 'CMS',
        'PORT': 27017,
    }
}

# Configure MongoDB for sessions
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.mongo'
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True

# MongoDB configuration for sessions
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django_mongoengine.sessions'
SESSION_MONGO_DB = 'CMS'  # Use the same MongoDB database name as your main database
SESSION_MONGO_COLLECTION = 'django_sessions'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

`core/views.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from mongoengine import DoesNotExist

from authentication.models import SignUp


def home(request):
    default_content = {
        'title': 'Welcome to College Management System',
    }
    # Retrieve the username from cookies
    username = request.session.get('username')

    if username:
        try:
            user = SignUp.objects.get(username=username)
            # Your existing code that uses user_id goes here
            # For example, you can fetch additional user data using user_id
            # Update default_content or perform other actions based on user information
        except DoesNotExist:
            # Handle the case where the user does not exist
            return HttpResponse("User does not exist")

    return render(request, 'core/base.html', {'content': default_content, 'username': username})
```

`base.html`

```
<!-- base.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ content.title }}</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'core/base.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
            <li class="register"><a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Signup</a></li>
            <li class="register"><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div>
    {% if username %}
        <h2>Welcome, {{ username }}!</h2>
        <a href="{% url 'user_logout' %}">Logout</a>
    {% else %}
        <p>You are not logged in.</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% block content %}
    {% if error_message %}
        <p class="alert alert-danger">{{ error_message }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```